# Locating resource for OpenMP + MPI application

Tags: c++, mpi, openmp, pbs

I'm currently developing a hybrid program using c++. I'm using both openMP and MPI. However, I don't know how to specify the number of processors and threads for my job. Let's say that I want to use 5 nodes and I want one MPI processor on each node and I want 24 threads per node.

This is how I submit `my_job` right now:

```
qsub -l select=5:ncpus=24:mpiprocs=5 -l place=scatter:exclhost my_job
```

and on `my_job` script, I'm doing this

```
#PBS -l select=5:ncpus=24:mpiprocs=5
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=24
mpic++ -O3 myprogram.cpp -o out -fopenmp -lquadmath -std=gnu++11
mpirun -n 5 ./out
```

However, the performance is very slow, which make me think that there might be a problem with how I'm locating my resources.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per https://www2.cisl.ucar.edu/resources/computational-systems/cheyenne/running-jobs/pbs-pro-job-script-examples that would be

```
#PBS -l select=5:ncpus=24:mpiprocs=1:ompthreads=24
```

Comment: Thanks Gilles, I think this may solve the problem. I will try it now and see if there is any difference in performance. Appreciate your help.

Comment: That is something missing beside I forget to specify number of processor per node when running the job: mpirun -n 5 -ppn 1 ./out

Comment: which MPI library are you using ? if this is Open MPI and it was built with tm support, then that should not be needed at all.

Comment: I'm using MPICH2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gilles, I also forget to specify the number of processor per node when running the job:

```
mpirun -n 5 -ppn 1 ./out
```

Moreover, I have added this line to `my_job` script:

```
export IPATH_NO_CPUAFFINITY=1 // - tells the underlying software not to pin each process to one CPU core, which would effectively disable OpenMP parallelism.
```

both solutions had improved performance "a lot".